# How to make the cmder add the line number in history command?

Tags: git-bash, line-numbers, cmder

Normally when using the command `history` on git bash the result has a line number.

[image: history result in git bash]

But using `cmder`, the result of `history` command has no line number on the start of each line. As you can see below.

[image: history result in cmder]

How can I configure `cmder` to add line numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this one hasn't been answered yet. I just found out that **cmder** natively supports the bash shell and you can switch to it just by executing it with `bash` command or you can switch shells by pressing the add button with the green background.